# Using bootstrap with angular 2 mix ng-bootstrap and "native" bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I would like to start off with a new Angular 2 Project. Since I want to use Bootstrap 3 for a UI, I wonder what is best practice here?

Can I mix ng-bootstrap and the "native" bootstrap together?
For example, I couldn´t find a navbar directive in ng-bootstrap. So I have to build it with "native" bootstrap, right?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's ok because ng-boostrap just add some ng2 components to your application (and a lot of documentation and examples, thanks to them). Bootstrap CSS will work natively with html tags, attribute and classes.

I suggest you to take a look at [sources here](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap), you will see that there are no more javascript or ressources than native library :

> Welcome to the Angular 2 version of the Angular UI Bootstrap library. This library is being built from scratch by the ui-bootstrap team. We are using TypeScript and targeting the Bootstrap 4 CSS framework.

Comment: So I can just install ng-bootstrap and have full bootstrap functionalities? I wonder because there is no jQuery in there e.g.

Comment: No, you have to install Bootstrap manually in your app. In my case I just added this line in my index.html file : `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` but they suggest to use Bootstrap 4 available (in beta) here : https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com

Comment: But still I just need the CSS part of bootstrap? Or Jquery as well?

Comment: For the native use, you'll need the jQuery (and Tether somtimes ?) libraries. You can install it properly with npm : `npm install jquery --save` then `import $ from "jquery"`